# Query for repeated ndb.KeyProperty not working

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

What's wrong with my query?

**Here are my models:**

```
class Positions(ndb.Model):
  title = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=True)
  summary = ndb.TextProperty()
  duties = ndb.TextProperty()
  dateCreated = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
  dateUpdated = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now=True)

class Applicants(ndb.Model):
  name = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=True)
  position = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=Positions,repeated=True)
  file = ndb.BlobKeyProperty()
  dateCreated = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
  dateUpdated = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now=True)
```

**Here is my query:**

```
class AdminPositionInfoHandler(BaseHandler):
  def get(self,positionKeyId):
    user = users.get_current_user()
    if users.is_current_user_admin():
      positionKey = ndb.Key('Positions',int(positionKeyId))
      position = positionKey.get()
      applicants = Applicants.query(position=position.key).fetch() # the query
      values = {
        'position': position,
        'applicants': applicants,
      }
      self.render_html('admin-position-info.html',values)
    else:
      self.redirect(users.create_login_url(self.request.uri))
```

**What seems to be wrong in using the query:**

```
applicants = Applicants.query(position=position.key).fetch()
```

**I got this error:**

```
File "C:\xampp\htdocs\angelstouch\main.py", line 212, in get
applicants = Applicants.query(position=position.key).fetch()
... 
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'position'
```

**I also tried using `positionKey` instead of `position.key`:**

```
applicants = Applicants.query(position=positionKey).fetch()
```

I got this from "Ancestor Queries" section of GAE site:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't pass arguments to query like that - ndb uses overridden equality/inequality operators, so you can express queries more 'naturally', with '==', '<', '>' etc., so:

```
applicants = Applicants.query(Applications.position==position.key).fetch()
```

The section in the on [Filtering by Property Values](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries#filter_by_prop) gives some more examples.

(ancestor is a special-case for queries - it isn't a model property)

Comment: This is not an ordinary query. I'm using ndb.KeyProperty(). Please refer to the example link given in the section "Ancestor Queries". https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries#ancestor

Comment: Just because you are using a KeyProperty does not mean it is an ancestor. Doing ancestor queries are specific to querying based on the parent set when making the Entity. Since you are querying against a normal property you can just use a normal filter, as mentioned by @Greg.

Comment: Hmmm... I changed the position attribute to repeated=False. Then, it worked. I'm going to stick with this because it seems to be the natural way in relational database. Although it does not seem to answer the question how to use it with repeated.